# UIImageView not showing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am loading image with text in my ViewController. The text loads and it's fine but the image doesnt.

Here is how I load them in my ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tut_1.jpeg"];
    self.titleLabel.text = self.titleText;
      NSLog(@"%@",  self.backgroundImageView);
      NSLog(@"%@",  self.backgroundImageView.image);
      NSLog(@"%@",  self.titleLabel.text);

}
```

The output of the NSLogs is "some text" for  the self.titleLabel.text and NULL for the self.backgroundImageView.image.

Strange because NSLog of `self.backgroundImageView` is not NIL but:

> UIImageView: 0x14deaffb0; frame = (0 0; 240 128); autoresize = RM+BM;
>   userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer =

The image `tut_1.jpeg` exits and the name is written correctly.

I also have the correct outlet referencing in my header file by dragging from the interface builder:

[image]

Comment: Try only writing `tut_1`and not `tut_1.jpeg`

Comment: Try to create UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tut_1.jpeg"]; to check if the image is in asset ?

Comment: Do you use auto layout in your project?

Comment: Yes, I use auto layout.

Comment: When you declare and UIImage before set it to the UIImageView, is it also nil? Like this: UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tut_1.jpeg"];

Comment: Yes @UlasSancak its also nil

Comment: So the only explanation here is the file can't be found or it is not an image file that UIImage can handle.

Comment: Right. I converted the file from JPEG to PNG and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. As @Ulas Sancak said the file I was referencing `[UIImage imageNamed:@"tut_1.jpeg"]` couldn't be handled by UIImage. So I simply converted the image from jpeg to PNG format and it worked !

Comment: Great! I am glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

#### Possibility 1:

> I also have the correct outlet referencing in my header file by dragging from the interface builder

No, you don't. If you log, you will see that `self.backgroundImageView` is `nil`, because the outlet from the nib is not hooked up to it.

#### Possibility 2:

> The image tut_1.jpeg exits and the name is written correctly

No, it doesn't. If you log `[UIImage imageNamed:@"tut_1.jpeg"]`, you will see that it is `nil`.

Comment: You are right about the image. I tried by referencing other images from the project that appearing and still have NULL when NSLog. So how should I reference an image in that case ?

Comment: I cannot see your project. Only you can see it. I've answered the question you asked - and I've taught you something about how to debug _before_ you waste time asking questions on Stack Overflow. If you have a new question, about _why_ your image reference is `nil`, please feel free to ask it as a new separate question.